# How to pass image in fetch and save the same in php action to upload t to server?

Tags: php, react-native

How to upload and handle image in react native and php?

React-native code:

```
let img = new FormData();
img.append('file', {
    filename: 'image.jpg',
    filepath: this.state.image.uri,
    contentType: 'image/jpeg', 
});    

Fetch(`action url?f=createComplaint&otp_code=${this.props.OTPInputText}&cp_phone_no=${this.props.phno}&cp_relationship=${this.props.Relationship}&cp_name=${this.props.Name}&cp_email_id=${this.props.email}
                        &cp_address=${this.props.address}&cp_complaint_type=${this.props.complianttype}&cp_district=${this.props.location}&cp_compliant_details=${this.props.summary}&otp_code=${this.props.OTPInputText}&cp_resp_name=${this.props.RName}&cp_resp_phone_no=${this.props.Rphno}&cp_resp_email_id=${this.props.Remail}&cp_resp_address=${this.props.address}&cd_name=${this.state.CName}
                     &cd_gender=${this.state.cGender}+&cd_age=${this.state.cAge}&cd_indentification=${this.state.cIDMark}&cd_photo=${img}`)
```

PHP Code:

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    $addphoto= explode(".",basename($_FILES['cd_photo']['name']));
    $cd_photo = date('Ymdhis').rand(0,999).".".$addphoto[1];
    $pathPhoto = '../child_photos/'.$cd_photo;

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cd_photo']['tmp_name'], $pathPhoto)) {

    }
```

I get `[object][object]` in my url for img